# ImportError no module named tests

Tags: python

I would like perform this import:

```
from tests.db.connection_tests import ConnectionTests
```

where tests contains a module named db.

I am getting `ImportError: No module named 'tests.db'`.

The structure of tests is:

```
tests
    |
    db
        |
        connection_tests.py
    |
    moduleA
```

The problem seems to be that Python already has a module called tests. The only option that came to my mind was to rename the tests module.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `PYTHONPATH` env variable to the path upto your tests folder.